# Weierstrass division theorem for henselian rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, schemes, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be an henselian local noetherian ring. There is an old result of Lafon ("Anneaux henséliens et théorème de préparation" (1967)), which says that if $A$ is analytically normal and of characteristic zero, then it verifies Weierstrass preparation theorem.

Is there any progress on this? Is the analytic normality essential and what happens in characteristic p?

Comment: A lovely question. Are there no examples known of Henselian non-Weierstrassable rings?

Comment: What is the statement of the Weierstrass preparation here? That any $f \in R[[x]]$, nonzero mod $m$, is equal to a unit of $R[[x]}$? times a monic polynomial in $R[x}$? It seems to me that, if this holds in a local ring $R$, then it holds in any quotient of $R$ with the same maximal ideal. So it could be possible to prove this in Noetherian non-analytically normal rings by viewing them as quotients of analytically normal rings.

Comment: I cannot find the paper you are referring to. Could you please explain briefly how that works? For example, when I have a Henselian pair $(A,I)$, how can I do a Weierstrass division of some formal power series $f\in R[[x]]$ by the simplest "Weierstrass polynomial" $x-a$ where $a\in I$? Seemingly this will force me to "evaluate" $f(a)$ in $R$, which seems impossible without any kind of completeness of $R$?